# need to know how to implement Oauth 2.0 with Django/MySQL

Tags: ios, django, oauth-2.0

I have a Django/MySQL backend and iOS frontend. What can I do for authentication for OAUTH 2.0? This is my first time implementing Oauth so I would like to understand what is involved. What are some good blogs/books/etc so I could check it out?

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Client) client in  combination with [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).